# Show data of table in vertical manner using sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2017

```
  Cid  EmpId1 EmpName1 EmpId2 EmpName2
  1    109    Emanuel  256    Sally

select * from emp where cid = 1;
```

This will query will give me output in horizontal manner.
How to get the output in vertical manner using SQL query.

Expected output

```
Emp1     109
EmpName1 Emanuel
Emp2     256
EmpName2 Sally
```

I have 50 emp IDs and Emp names in the table as columns. I did not want to go with `union all`
Here is what I tried using `unpivot`

```
select Id from (
select Emp1 ,Emp2 from emp where cid = 1) as upvt
Unpivot
(Id for IDs in (Emp1,Emp2))as upvt
```

How do I include `EmpName` to this is

Comment: 'unpivot' i would have a play with

Comment: I assume you also want Cid in the result?

Comment: @jarlh cid not required.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I'm unable to add EmpName to unpivot. Could you help.

Comment: You will need to add it to your select